# Problem with using annotation @riverpod in working with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod, riverpod-annotation

Im following offical documentation and while trying to use @riverpod annotation in my code im getting error: "Undefined class 'HelloWorldRef' "

I tried to create provider like in documentation:

```dart
@riverpod
String helloWorld(HelloWorldRef ref) {
  return 'Hello world';
}
```

Comment: did you let the builder run, and did you add the proper part file?

Comment: I'm sure there is missing `part 'your_filename.g.dart';` directive

Comment: Yes, that was problem, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have first to ensure that you have all packages installed in your project.

```bash
flutter pub add flutter_riverpod
flutter pub add riverpod_annotation
flutter pub add dev:riverpod_generator
flutter pub add dev:build_runner
flutter pub add dev:custom_lint
flutter pub add dev:riverpod_lint
```

now you can run the code-generator with `flutter pub run build_runner watch`